# Date query in laravel : start datetime with current

Tags: laravel

Greeting.
I have One datetime in my table. Its name is start_time. And I have a variable(process_time) that contains the number of seconds to run a process. How to count the number of fields with the following condition:
start_time + process_timen < Present time

Comment: Usually you should include the code you have tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `DB::raw()` helper and add the SQL equivelant of what you want to achieve using `DATE_ADD` and `INTERVAL`.

```
$processTime = 15; // seconds

Model::where(DB::raw("DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL $processTime second)"), '<', now())->count();
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind consideration. It worked very well